# Как правильно создавать ЧПУ для товаров?

Tags: php, mvc, чпу

Всем привет. Скажите, пожалуйста, как правильно создавать похожие ЧПУ: `site.com/products/51-rosa-entry-ticket-19599`?

Т.е. чтобы сначала шли несколько слов из названия товара из БД, а затем через `-` id товара, по которому уже будем искать. И как правильно их распарсить на бэкэнде, чтобы верно выдавать товары, т.е. через id? Это с помощью регулярок делается? Заранее спасибо!

Сайт с единой точкой доступа, сделан на паттерне MVC, пишу на php

Comment: @Даниил пишу на php, обновил пост

Comment: Совмещение id записи и его алиаса нужно ТОЛЬКО если у Вас алиасы у товаров/категорий буду совпадать, в большинстве случаев достаточно одного алиаса